# How do I flush buffer in AudioRecord object?

Tags: java, android, audio, media

I am trying to get very accurately timed recordings from the microphone on my android device.  My thought was something like

```
while (true) {
  audioRecord.startRecording();
  sleep(0,nanoSeconds);
  audioRecord.flush();
  audioRecord.read(buf, 0, numSamples);
}
```

But there is no `flush()` method for `AudioRecord`.  So perhaps I should do

```
while (true) {
  sleep(0,nanoSeconds);
  audioRecord.startRecording();
  audioRecord.read(buf, 0, numSamples);
  audioRecord.stop();
}
```

Of course, I cannot find documentation on what `startRecording()`, `read()`, and `stop()` do in sufficient detail to where they actually talk about a buffer.  There do not seem to be any methods to call which tell me whether the buffer has samples in it.  Or that let me make a read() call which reads all the existing buffer out: I need to specify the number of samples to read and my call will block until those samples exist.

I'd love for someone to show me where this is more truly documented.  But nearly as good, just tell me what I should do if I am really trying to get the microphone started at a very accurately determined start time.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the source code is probably more helpful than the documentation. Most of Android's media classes are a thin wrapper around native code. The [`startRecording()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/media/AudioRecord.java#AudioRecord) method, for example, simply calls [`android_media_AudioRecord_start()`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/core/jni/android_media_AudioRecord.cpp#257) in the JNI layer, which in turn calls `start()` on a native [AudioRecord instance](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/media/libmedia/AudioRecord.cpp#285). Beyond that, it interfaces with the [`AudioFlinger`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/media/libmedia/AudioSystem.cpp#49) and eventually the hardware drivers. The hardware latencies will almost certainly vary between devices, and the components are typically not designed for high-precision work.

With that said, if you can make some assumptions about the hardware on which your app will be running, then reading through the native code linked above may be helpful. And if you're comfortable writing a bit of C++ (JNI) code, you can access the audio buffer by manipulating an instance of `AudioRecord`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since API level 24, you can call AudioRecord.getAudioTimestamp() for frame delivery information at the earliest point available in the capture pipeline. Therefore, you may compare the timestamps after starting recording to see if they differ by the sleep interval.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getTimestamp(android.media.AudioTimestamp,%20int)) for details.